# Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'double[]

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing function that encapsulate query in lambda expression and i wanted to return query result in the form of array but it is giving error on the last line of code:- Error is following:-

Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'double[]

query is following which is giving above error on last line of code:

```
 public double[] PopulateGrid()
    {
        using (var db = new hdContext())
        {
            var query = db.tickets.Join(
                db.employees, t => t.CreatedBy, e => e.EmployeeId, (t, e) => new
                {
                    t.Id,
                    t.EmployeeName,
                    e.Employee_Name,
                    e.Department,
                    e.Location,
                    t.Subject,
                    t.MainCatId,
                    t.SubCatId,
                    t.PickTicket,
                    t.Status,
                    t.CreateDate
                }).Join
                (
                db.MainCategory, t => t.MainCatId, m => m.MainCatId, (t, m) => new
                {
                    t.Id,
                    t.EmployeeName,
                    t.Employee_Name,
                    t.Department,
                    t.Location,
                    t.Subject,
                    t.MainCatId,
                    m.MainCatName,
                    t.SubCatId,
                    t.PickTicket,
                    t.Status,
                    t.CreateDate
                }).ToArray();

            return query;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. The last parameter of the `Join` method is the result selector (which determines what the query returns), and in your case you're returning an anonymous type:

```
new
{
    t.Id,
    t.EmployeeName,
    t.Employee_Name,
    t.Department,
    t.Location,
    t.Subject,
    t.MainCatId,
    m.MainCatName,
    t.SubCatId,
    t.PickTicket,
    t.Status,
    t.CreateDate
}
```

Obviously you can't convert this type to a `double`, so you probably want to select a specific field using `.Select(z => z.MyDoubleField)` before materializing your entities with `ToArray()`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Actually I have button on form and I dont want to write above code in button so iam trying to write a separate function to write above code. I dont know how to return anonymous type and get in button. Also u can see I have multiple table/entities colums/properties in above code so iam comfuse that what should be return type in function or how to return anonymous type.  Plz suggest appropriately, thanks.